# Invalid block tag on line 2: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm having some difficulties on building a simple menu navigation bar. I need to make a highlight on current menu tab which the user is browsing on. So I'm working with Django and Jinja2, and here's my code:

*page1.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% set active_page = "menu1" %}

{% block title %}Apie mus{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

{{page}} - Current Page set from django return
...
```

My *base.html*:

```
...
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item {{ 'active' if active_page == 'menu1' else '' }}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'apie_mus' %}">Apie mus </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do things in proper way and set `active` css class for the current active page, here how you can do

in `templates/includes/header.html`:

```
..

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

  <li class="nav-item{% if request.path == '/' %} active{% endif %}"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

  <li class="nav-item{% if request.path == '/about' %} active{% endif %}"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>

</ul>

..
```

and then in `templates/base.html`:

```
.. 

<body>

  {% include 'includes/header.html' %}
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  {% include 'includes/footer.html' %}

..
```

and you don't need `{% set .. %}`

refer to this [topic](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#assignments) **templates assignments** for more details

Comment: Thanks man, this `{% if request.path == '/' %}`fixed my issue.